# How to obtain id of the surronding list item in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to use jQuery tabs but there is an issue that I can't resolve.

Somewhere inside the document's body, I have:

```
<ul class="tabs-horizontal">
    <li id="a" class="current"><a href="#">Tab A</a></li>
    <li id="b"><a href="#">Tab B</a></li>
</ul>
```

In my script section, I have:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function(){

        var activeTabIndex = -1;
        var tabNames = ["a","b"];

        $(".tabs-horizontal > li").click(function(e){
            for(var i=0;i<tabNames.length;i++) {
                if(e.target.id == tabNames[i]) {
                    activeTabIndex = i;
                } else {
                    $("#"+tabNames[i]).removeClass("current");
                }
            }
            $("#"+tabNames[activeTabIndex]).addClass("current");
            return false;
        });
    });

</script>
```

It doesn't work because I'm comparing `e.target.id` with `tabNames` elements. When I debugged, I found `e.target.id` returns `-1`.

So, how can I obtain those two `li` IDs (i.e. `"a"` and `"b"`)?

Thanks.

Comment: try `this.id` instead `e.target.id`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$(".tabs-horizontal > li").click(function(e) {
      $(this).addClass("current").siblings().removeClass("current");
      return false;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Inside a jQuery event handler, `this` will be the DOM element on which you hooked the event. Since you're hooking the event on the `li` elements, `this.id` will be their ID.

But you don't need the ID. You can just use traversal to do what you're trying to do. I was about to show how, but [undefined already has](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17184416/157247).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
$(".tabs-horizontal > li").click(function () {
    $('li.current').removeClass("current");
    $(this).addClass("current");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

e.target points to the a link inside the li. you should use `e.target.parentElement.id`

Comment: *"you should use `e.target.parentElement.id`"* While the OP *can* use that, they probably shouldn't. :-)